# null Object Reference though initialised

Tags: android

I am getting null pointer exception as Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.webkit.WebSettings android.webkit.WebView.getSettings()' on a null object reference

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   WebView wb;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    wb.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
 }
public class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
     }
   }
}
```

here is .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the snippet of my manifest.xml file...

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
               <data android:scheme="http"
                   android:host="www.google.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post the logcat error

Comment: please show .xml file

Comment: Add the code of activity_main.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webview is null. 
Add a webview to xml and refer that webview in your java code.

Comment: yes in your layout.xml. It is recommended to read through android docs

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your variable `WebView`.
You're trying to instantiate it by finding the associated view in your activity layout, aka. this line:

```
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
```

Because your XML file doesn't have any views with tag "*web*", the method `findViewById(R.id.web)` is returning `null`. And here comes your error. You're trying to call (invoke) a method `getSettings()` on a *null* object, which is illegal.

To fix that, you need to add the *WebView* in your XML. For example, your XML could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```